# DELPHI "the object invoked has disconnected from its clients"

Tags: delphi

When excel runs, the data file that I process is opened. (and my program stops if I close this file)

```
unit UBImportFromExcel;

interface

uses
  MainDM, Contnrs, DB, Classes, UGeneral, BSYSTMGlobals,
  SysUtils, ADODB, BDataSet, NThermo, ComObj, Graphics, Forms, ShellAPI, Windows, Math, DBClient;

type

  TBImportFromExcel = class
    private
      ExcelApp, ExcelWorkbook, ExcelWorksheet,
      Unassigned : Variant;
      iStartingRow : Integer;
      iSheetCount : Integer;
      iRowCount : Integer;
    public
      function ReadCell(iRow : Integer; iColumn : Integer) : string;
      procedure Worksheet(iWorksheetIndex : integer = 1);
    protected

    published
      property StartingRow : Integer read iStartingRow write iStartingRow;
      property SheetCount : Integer read iSheetCount;
      property RowCount : Integer read iRowCount;

      constructor Create(sFile : string); virtual;
      destructor Destroy; override;
  end;


implementation

{ TBImportFromExcel }

constructor TBImportFromExcel.Create(sFile : string);
begin
  ExcelApp        := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  ExcelWorkbook   := ExcelApp.WorkBooks.Open(sFile);
  iSheetCount     := ExcelWorkbook.Worksheets.Count;
  iStartingRow    := 2;
end;

destructor TBImportFromExcel.Destroy;
begin
  ExcelWorkbook.Close(False);
  ExcelWorksheet := Unassigned;
  ExcelWorkbook := Unassigned;
  ExcelApp := Unassigned;
  inherited;
end;

function TBImportFromExcel.ReadCell(iRow, iColumn: Integer): string;
var
  oCell : OleVariant;
begin
  oCell       := ExcelWorksheet.Cells[iRow, iColumn];
  Result      := oCell.Value;
end;

procedure TBImportFromExcel.Worksheet(iWorksheetIndex: integer);
begin
  ExcelWorksheet  := ExcelWorkbook.Worksheets.Item[iWorksheetIndex];
  ExcelWorksheet.Activate;
  ExcelWorksheet.Select;
  iRowCount       := ExcelWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
end;

end.
```

[image: img1]
[image: img2]
[image: img3]

If the excel file opened by itself is closed, I get the error in the header and my program is breaking.
sorry for my bad english. createoleobject cannot create a standalone object. why?

Comment: Your English isn't really a problem, but I'm afraid the texts in your screenshots are, as they seem to contain the only diagnostic information in your q and ought really to be provided in English.  If you are worried about the user causing a problem for your app by closing Excel, the way you can minimse the risk of that is not to make your ExcelOle object visible, which you can achieve by ExcelApp.Visible := False.  Not sure what you mean by "createoleobject cannot create a standalone object. why?", so you will need to explain that as best you can.

Comment: I made ExcelApp.Visible = False. but if any excel file is opened from the desktop, ExcelApp.Visible = True the file I processed is visible again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, I think I *may* have a solution to your problem.

As well as `Visible`, Excel's OLE object has two other relevant properties:

- `DisplayAlerts` which determines whether alerts produced by the Exccel application
  are displayed on-screen; and
- `Interactive`, which determines whether the Excel object (created using CreateOleObject)
  can interact with an instance of Excel started by the user via the Windows gui.  If it is set to False,
  the Excel OLE instance is completely "insolated" from the user's desktop instance.

Both of these are documented by MS, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.interactive)
for the documentation for `Interactive`.

So I created a simple test app with just two buttons and two checkboxes and this code

```
procedure TForm1.Start;
begin
  sFile := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'Test.Xlsx';
  ExcelApplication := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');

  ExcelApplication.Interactive := cbInteractive.Checked;
  ExcelApplication.Visible := cbVisible.Checked;
  ExcelApplication.DisplayAlerts := ExcelApplication.Visible; // no point in displaying alerts if Excel app is not visible

  ExcelWorkbook  := ExcelApplication.WorkBooks.Open(sFile);
end;

procedure TForm1.Stop;
begin
  ExcelWorkBook.Close;  // Needed to hide Excel if it was started with Visible = True
  ExcelApplication.Quit;
  ExcelWorkBook := Unassigned;
  ExcelApplication := Unassigned;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnStopClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Stop;
end;
```

Setting the cbInteractive checkbox to False does indeed appear to isolate the OLE-created instance from any interactively-created one.

Anyway, have an experiment with that and see if it meets your needs.

Comment: Has this answered your question or not?  If not, why not?